# Sagemaker Clarify Job keeps returning ClientError: Threshold values must be provided for continuous features

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

Data Config

```
from sagemaker import clarify


data_config_unbalanced = clarify.DataConfig(
    s3_data_input_path='s3://a/b.csv', # S3 object path containing the unbalanced dataset
    s3_output_path='s3://a/', # path to store the output
    label='My Categorical Target Column', # target column
    headers=df.columns.to_list(),
    dataset_type='text/csv',
)
```

Clarify Config

```
bias_config_unbalanced = clarify.BiasConfig(
    label_values_or_threshold=['Yes'], # desired sentiment
    facet_name='My facet continous int column' # sensitive column (facet)
)
```

Any ideas how to resolve `Clarify Job keeps returning ClientError: Threshold values must be provided for continuous features` from clarify job. Documentation was not very helpful

Comment: Are you running a processing job or using the container?